# Is there a word for when you offer an incorrect solution to a problem/ error, based on a misconception/ misunderstanding?

Tags: single-word-requests

Hope the example isn't too strange, but here we go!

Recounting the name of a piece of music to a friend, I told him to look up the name incorrectly.

- The name of the piece was "From Darkness, Light: III" (roman 3)
- I misread the numerals and recounted this as "From Darkness, Light: 11" (eleven)
- I corrected myself to "From Darkness, Light: II" (roman two)

I'm still incorrect because of a misconception from earlier on.
Is there a name for this sort of error?

Comment: It's known as a "mistake".

Comment: "Oops!" works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider this an example of a ***compounded error***, that is, an error which results from another error. I've heard this phrase used before and it comes naturally to me, but I'm not sure if it has conventionalized enough to be in the public lexicon.

Actually, the situation you describe is an example of a special type of compounded error, one where the original error is partially noticed and an attempt is made to correct it, but which correction is still based on the original error.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, you can refer to this situation as a [GIGO](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/GIGO) (pronounced guy-go), an acronym for *g*arbage *i*n, *g*arbage *o*ut.

The term originates from the world of computing, asserting that if input is faulty, then so too will output be faulty, regardless of the quality of the program which processes that input.